# set ul li list in float for position

Tags: html, css

this is my html code:-

```
<div id="load">
<ul>
    <li>Activities
    <div>
    <ul>
        <li>Physical1
        <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Cricket
            <div>
            <ul>
                <li>One Day</li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Test1
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>Test At Abc</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Test2
            <div>
            <ul>
        <li>Test At Xyz</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

this is my css:-

```
li{
color:red;
border-left:1px solid green;
}
li{
list-style:none;
}
ul > li > div > ul {
    display: none;  // hide all submenus

}

li:hover > div > ul {
    display: block; // show sub menu when parent li is hovered
}
```

now i want to something this type of my list:-
[image]

i think using proper position css style its done.
or with float i think its possible.
any kind help well come...
thanks...

Comment: [multilevel dropdown menu](http://www.noupe.com/css/multilevel-drop-down-navigation-menus-examples-and-tutorials.html)

Comment: Are you displaying data (table?) or a navigation menu?